# Boto:Help me i am getting this error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
import boto3
 >>> client = boto3.client('ec2')
     >>> response = client.create_tags(DryRun = True | False, Resources = ['ABC', ], Tags = [{
                'Key' : 'vennkata',
                'Value' : 'ratnam'
            }, ])
    Traceback(most recent call last) :
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in < module >
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError : Could not connect to the endpoint URL : "https://ec2.us-west.amazonaws.com/"
```

Can anyone provide suggestions to avoid this error @ the time of creating a snapshot using volume id?

Answer (score 4):

Could not connect to the endpoint URL : https://ec2.**us-west**.amazonaws.com

`us-west` is not a valid region. Currently supported regions are `us-west-1` and `us-west-2`. See 
[AWS Regions and Endpoints - Amazon Web Services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region) You must have misconfigured the region. Check **~/.aws/config** and fix it or set the correct value in the shell.

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1
```